# sendmail hangs / mail hangs

Tags: email, sendmail

On all computers, sendmail works great except for one.

All have the exact same /etc/mail config folder setup, I used rsync to make sure they all match.

Normally this command works just fine...

sendmail -t < my-email-file.eml

But from this one computer (all are running Ubuntu 20.04) the process just hangs.

I tried "sendmail -t" which lets me compose an email directly from the command line. I get to the CTRL+D and nothing happens. I tried using the command "mail my@address.com" and was able to compose and when I get to the cc: line it hangs. Pressing CTRL+Z breaks me out and eventually the email sends.

What is going on that is causing sendmail/mail to hang at the end of file?

There doesn't seem to be any way to completely uninstall and reinstall. I have tried "apt-get purge sendmail" and the system says it is uninstalled but typing sendmail on the commandline still gets me into a text editor mode and still sends email. And "whereis sendmail" still shows it in /usr/sbin

I simply cannot figure out what is going on here. Why is it hanging at EOF? And why only on this one computer?

Thanks!

---- UPDATE ----
I really don't know how to read the strace output but it was suggested. The output looks mostly the same on all machines with this part being the tail end...

```
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = 0
sendto(3, "<18>May  6 12:27:19 sendmail[265"..., 120, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 120
write(2, "Program mode requires special pr"..., 69Program mode requires special privileges, e.g., root or TrustedUser.
) = 69
alarm(0)                                = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ALRM], [], 8) = 0
getpid()                                = 26521
setuid(1000)                            = 0
exit_group(78)                          = ?
+++ exited with 78 +++
```

But on the one computer that is getting stuck, things halt here at the clock_nanosleep which is not in the others.

```
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = 0
sendto(3, "<18>May  6 12:27:57 sendmail[688"..., 100, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 100
clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=60, tv_nsec=0},
```

Here is some info about sendmail on this server:

```
$ which sendmail
/usr/sbin/sendmail

$ ls -l $(which sendmail)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Feb  3 15:51 /usr/sbin/sendmail -> /etc/alternatives/sendmail

$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/sendmail
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 May  6 06:39 /etc/alternatives/sendmail -> /usr/libexec/sendmail/sendmail
```

The end point on other servers stop at /usr/lib/sm.bin/sendmail but I am not sure why the laptop with the issue ends at libexec/sendmail since they all run ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: I would try to add strace -> `strace sendmail -t < my-email-file.eml`. At least you'll be able to see what is the last call ... and /usr/sbin/sendmail could be an alias, see `ls -l $(which sendmail)`

Comment: I added some output from strace and looked at the location of sendmail. I added it to the original question.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=jammy&keywords=%2Fusr%2Flibexec%2Fsendmail%2Fsendmail&searchon=contents ... this shows the package `sendmail.bin` is installed. So it semes not to be alternative/replacement. Good ...

Comment: Ive seen the `clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME,...` line before, related to a process prioritization issue while playing with motion capturing. It works well on the dev system, but not at a laptop 'in production'. The issue was something with the energy gouvenor, we needed to set it from 'ondemand' to 'performance', to get it work. I don't know if this will help in your case.

Comment: I am in performance mode. Just typing sendmail -t hangs. CTRL+C is the only way out.

Answer (score 0):

I just went down this wormhole with the same 60 second delay.

I did not have syslogd, but after installing it, this appeared in /var/log/messages

```
May 12 17:52:43 myhost mail.crit sendmail[6955]: My unqualified host name (myhost) unknown; sleeping for retry 
May 12 17:52:47 myhost mail.crit sendmail[6960]: My unqualified host name (myhost) unknown; sleeping for retry 
May 12 17:52:52 myhost mail.crit sendmail[6974]: My unqualified host name (myhost) unknown; sleeping for retry
```

Try changing the hostname (and /etc/hosts) to a FQDN - myhost.localdomain or something similar.

Comment: I have syslogd installed. The delay isn't just for 60 seconds either. For me it is forever. Also have FQDN too in hosts.

Comment: That is unfortunate. My delay was 60-120 seconds, and sendmail finally would respond. My strace looked the same, with it getting stuck at clock_nanosleep. I spent all morning on this issue, but it was resolved once I changed the hostname. (Which was itself a problem as this was a docker container.)

Comment: I forgot to mention I re-ran sendmailconfig once I updated the hostname.

Comment: Weird. I let it sit and after almost 5 minutes it finally sent the email!!!! I just never let it sit that long. I am trying the sendmailconfig and it looks like it has hung but I will just let it sit a while as well.

Comment: sendmailconfig finished, no change. Still hanging for almost 5 minutes. I will dig through my config files. They are the same files I used when running Ubuntu 20.04 so I wouldn't expect things to have changed. I have just upgraded to 22.04 on all machines. All work perfectly except this one and the config files look the same too. Something is not quite right. Thanks for the info, it seems it isn't hanging just getting temporarily stuck.

Comment: sendmailconfig also calls sendmail, so that will hang too with the same issue. If you have the 'My unqualified host name (myhost) unknown; sleeping for retry' message then the system hostname is the root issue.